# Как в yii2 организовать поиск по диапазону?

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте. Есть yii2, есть таблица столбец "цена". Подскажите, как организовать поиск по диапазону цен, к примеру: поиск от 100 до 200? Может есть модуль какой, или статья есть по реализации сего? Я поискал, но ничего толкового не нашел. Буду рад любой информации по этому поводу.

Comment: Добрый день! А что будет в данном случае представлять собой фильтр - поле ввода или выпадающий список с подготовленными вариантами?

Comment: Добрый. поле ввода

Comment: вы собираетесь в поле ввода вводить два числа через пробел или как?

Comment: два поля: "от" и "до")

Comment: Как пример GridView - https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-sortirovka-i-filtr-gridview-po-svyazannym-i-vychislyaemym-polyam.html. Там приведён пример с фильтрацией по имени. Вам надо сделать аналогично, передавая значения от и до, прописывая WHERE myField >= от AND myField <= до

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать расширение **kartik-v/yii2-grid**, которое позволяет использовать на GridView разнообразные типы колонок и всевозможные фильтры, включая нужный Вам

Ссылка на репозиторий:
https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid

примерная конфигурация для Вашей таблицы с колонкой "Цена" и фильтром по ней:

```
GridView::widget([
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'price',
            //в качестве фильтра будет использован виджет kartik\range\RangeInput
            'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_RANGE
        ]
    ]
])
```

К сожалению, по серверной стороне точно сказать не могу, но скорее всего там нужно будет отловить конкретное поле(или два) и вставить их в between в SQL-запросе
Хотя, не исключено, что расширение и это сделает за Вас!